# Google custom search shows outdated records

Tags: jsp, google-custom-search

I have created a custom search engine for my website using google custom search.For that I am using a different google account.The page on which custom search textfield appears has the following code:
`<script>
                      (function() {
                        var cx = '016767413532501348949:fxidfvgzwa0';
                        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                        gcse.async = true;
                        gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                            '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                      })();
                    </script>
                        <gcse:search></gcse:search>`

When I searched for a certain record say 'test' it used to show all test pages(html) created during early stages of developement.Then I removed these pages from my server and removed them from google's cache using webmaster tools https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ (I used same google account to achieve this and this page now shows that these pages are removed from cache).Again one of the jsp used to show links for these test records but now it doesn't show and even this jsp is indexed via by requesting to google.I do not understand why this jsp link is shown with those test records in custom search and when you click on this link it shows updated page.

Answer (score 0):

is this still the case? And are you talking about the actual data, eg from a file, or pages called test.html and similar? A re-crawl of your site should have happened by now to exclude those pages.

You can use the custom options of the cse tool to exclude particular pages or [exclude by url pattern](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631038?hl=en) to exclude the word test in page names or to exclude particular subdomains/directories. This might help you in the future. [url patterns](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/71826?hl=en)